# 4k показа или показов?

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено

Обратил внимание на разную форму написания количества показов:

[image: показ]

В одном случае - показ**ов**, в другом - показ**а**. Хотя и там, и там 4k.

Понятно, что окончание задаётся в зависимости от точного количества, например, 4002 показа, 4005 показов. Но, на мой взгляд, при написании 4k должно быть во всех случаях *показов*.

Что думаете по этому поводу?

Comment: А почему не "просмотров"? :)

Comment: Уже было: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/368/10105

Comment: @Visman, показы короче.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вообще показ**ов** (поскольку четыре тысячи показов), но уж если переводить на русский до конца, то вместо "4k" лучше писать "4 тыс.".

Comment: Кстати, да. Хорошее замечание. Интересно, могут это разработчики поправить? Или сильно поедет вёрстка?

Comment: 4к, 4кк, 4м уже прочно вписались в русский-интернетный, так что лучше оставить, исправить только падеж.

Comment: @ReinRaus мы разделяем перевод с Русским языком, где аудитория гораздо меньше пропитана русским-интернетным.

Comment: 4к как раз ок.
и да, я думаю, что лучше показов.
ибо "четыре тысячи показов"

Answer (score 18):

Точно так же думаем, должно быть **показов**.

Answer (score 4):

А ещё можно 4 килопоказа :)

Вообще да, "показов" логичнее. Но для меня не принципиально.