# Окончание числительных во вспывающей подсказке метки

Tags: дефект, локализация, метки

Блок, отображаемый при наведении на метку, содержит ошибочное окончание для числа вопросов. Примеры:

[image: c++]

[image: uwp]

Нашел, кажется, [правильные ресурсы](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40266057?key=fbafd75fe6d3365a419de6faa40e2d83) в transifex. Но тем не менее останется проблема с отображением большого кол-ва (с суфиксом `k`). Возможно, пригодится опыт при решении [проблемы с кол-вом показов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1446/4k-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2).