# Количество просмотров в тысячах. Неправильное окончание

Tags: дефект, локализация

Количество просмотров вопроса имеет неправильное окончание для тысяч (k). [Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/468496/176217):

> [image: 13k раза]

Должно быть "13k раз". Но, вероятно, просто берёт перевод на основании точного числа из подсказки.

Вопрос схож со старым [4k показа или показов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1446/176217), но там речь о числах в общем списке вопросов. И в этом плане сейчас всё нормально:

> [image: 13k показов]

Оформил запрос на MSE: [We need different string to translate for scaled view count on the question page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362829/339911)